# How to count number of occurrences of each string in a given array

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to programming and I try to write as simply as possible. I'm learning web development to do my own project and I spend few hours every day understanding the fundamentals of programming.  I would like to find the occurrence of characters in a given string using an array.

Here is my code in javascript:

```js
function fibonacciString(s) {
  var c = [];
  c = s.split("");
  var countOccuranceArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var countString = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      if (c[j] == c[i]) {
        countString++;
      }
    }
  }
  countOccuranceArray.push(countString);

  console.log(countOccuranceArray);
}

fibonacciString("aaabbbccc");
```

PS: I prefer not to change the structure but understand how can I position push() to add only the last count of occurrence. I hope you can make few tweaks to help me understand :D

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I'm guessing the output should be something like `{ a: 3, b: 3, c: 3 }`?

Comment: I think it would help to explain the algorithm in plain language, how would you solve this problem regardless of the programming language involved.

Comment: the output is : [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3] instead of [3,3,3]

Comment: you can use ascii values and store data according to ascii values and increment them.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of multiple possible solutions of your task. Of course, if I get you right.

```js
// Char counter function
fibonacciString = str => {
  // Create new object for chars
  const obj = {};
  
  // Loop string by counting it's length
  let i = str.length;
  while(i--) {
    // Use charAt to select char by index
    const char = str.charAt(i);
    
    // Now create object key with char name
    // and set number as it's value. If key
    // already exists, increase number
    obj[char] ? obj[char]++ : obj[char] = 1;
  }
  
  // Return result
  return obj;
}

// Test
console.log(fibonacciString("aaabbbccckkkkk"));
```

But if your task is to count REPEATED letters, then consider this:

```js
// Char counter function
fibonacciString = str => {
  // Create array for char number log
  const arr = [];
  
  // Set char counter
  let c = 0;
  
  // Loop string by counting it's length
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // Use charAt to select char by index
    const char = str.charAt(i);
    
    // Increase counter
    c++;
    
    // Compare previous char with current
    // and push number to array. If chars
    // not equals - reset counter to 1
    if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)) c = 1;
    
    // Push counter to array
    arr.push(c);
  }
  
  // Return result
  return arr;
}

// Test
console.log(fibonacciString("aaabbbccckkkkk"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the expected output. If I understood correctly then try this

```
function fibonacciString(s) {
   var c = [];
   c = s.split("");
   var countOccuranceArray = new Array(123).fill(0);// you can take the range of ascii characters. I have considered only alphabets
   var result = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
       var charCode = c[i].charCodeAt(0);
       countOccuranceArray[charCode] = countOccuranceArray[charCode] + 1;

       result.push(countOccuranceArray[charCode]);
    }

   console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a nested loop. Just use an object as a dictionary, add the characters as keys and update the values as you iterate over them. Then return the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
function fibonacciString(s) {

  // Create the object that you're going to store
  // the a, b, c etc as keys
  const obj = {};

  // Loop over the string
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    // Use the character at the string index as an object key
    const key = s[i];

    // If the key doesn't exist set the value to zero,
    // and then add 1
    if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = 0;
    obj[key]++;
  }

  // Finally return the object values which will be
  // an array of those numbers
  return Object.values(obj);

}

console.log(fibonacciString('aaabbbccc'));
```

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know object values even for.. in loops. gotta learn more!!

Comment: can you give me a link to learn more about this syntax :  (obj[key] || 0) + 1;

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the code better. Basically all it meant was "if the key exists on the object keep it and add one, otherwise set it to zero". The edit should make that clearer. PS: I've been at this 20 years and I'm still learning. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you, Andy, this is my 2nd week of coding, still new! Any help is appreciated :D